# JPA Hibernate Annotation Issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, entity

I have three Entities i'm modeling and am having issues with the associated annotations. I basically have a class that I intend on returning to the caller, a nested listed of Project's and the Project can contain a nested list of Endpoint's. It's a top-level has-a one-to-many, then the nested one-to-many has two one-to-many's.

I've played with `@JoinColumn` annotations, i've attempted to put a `@ManyToOne` on the other side of the OneToMany's (but it doesn't like that it's a Long..). I'm just fairly new and unsure on how to do this. I think the `mappedById` is the solution, but i'm uncertain.

**Main Issue:** This code allows me to "save" to the database, but upon retrieval, the list of Project's inside the DownDetectorPackage is empty.

A CascadeType.ALL throws referential integrity errors that I don't completely understand.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Builder                                                                               
public class DownDetectorPackage {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="id",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Project> projects;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dateJobsLastRan;
```

---

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Project{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String projectName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="id")
    private List<Service> externalDependencies;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="id")
    private List<Service> endpoints;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Service {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String url;
    private Boolean endpointIsUp;
    private String serviceName;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using @JoinColumn instead of mappedBy. MappedBy can be used when you have used @ManyToOne in the other class too, which you haven't.

So your final class should look something like this (this is applicable for the other classes too which you have mentioned) :

```
public class DownDetectorPackage {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@JoinColumn(name = "downDetectorPackageId")
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Project> projects;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dateJobsLastRan;
```

Also, remember to state the parent object name in @JoinColumn annotation, since it would create a column for that foreign key.

Comment: Need I make something transactional, or something? On save, I'm seeing the following error now with this setup -- HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.usaa.pc.property.downdetector.model.Project

Comment: If you encounter such an error, then check if you're already passing an "ID" for the newly created object i.e. Project.  It should be null, for a new entry.

Comment: I needed to CascadeType.ALL all of the collections -- this worked, though.

Answer (score 1):

You should mark every join column as JoinColumn denotating the referenced column from the other entity. Then, you are supposed to say which relation type are using this column.

```
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String projectName;

    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private ExternalDependencyEntity externalDependencies;

    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private EndpointEntity endpoints;
}
```

Finally, note that in a relational database, every fk column can takes only 1 value (pk of referenced entity id), so, on your entity, you should mark the data type as the entity you are refering to and no as a collection.

I think this sould solve your problem.

Comment: Need I make something transactional, or something? On save, I'm seeing the following error now with this setup -- HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.usaa.pc.property.downdetector.model.Project

Comment: I needed to CascadeType.ALL all of the collections -- this worked, though.

Comment: both answers were correct, he just helped by following up :(